# codeigniter 3 issue regarding updating the data through ajax crud

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have a problem in Ci i have crud operation read update and delete but I have changed these function to ajax request.
i am making update functionality through an Ajax request where I am using through the modal. i have values where i can edit these values when i edit these values and change and submit it will not go to success function. it will give me the error response. it will not submit on my server values. update values does not update on server side and not shown in my view. tell me where iam doing wrong. as iam a beginner and new in ci.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yneil.png)
show_item.php

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Include your form here -->
            <form id='editForm'>
              <div class="row">


                <div class="col-md-12">

                  <div class="box box-primary">
                    <div class="box-header with-border" style="background-color: #ECF0F5;">

                    </div>


                    <div class="box-body" style="background-color: #ECF0F5;">

                      <!-- <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row_brand["item_id"]; ?>"> -->
                      <input type="hidden" name="brand_id" value="<?php echo $row_brand["brand_id"]; ?>">
                      <input type="hidden" name="category_id"value="<?php echo $row_category["category_id"]; ?>">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-12">



                        <label for="brand">Brand</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="edit_brand_id" name="brand_id" disabled required autofocus="">
                          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Brand</option>

                          <?php foreach ($all_brand as $row_brand) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row_brand["brand_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row_brand["brand_name"]; ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select>

                        <label for="category">Category</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="edit_category_id" name="category_id" disabled required="">
                          <option value="1" disabled selected>Choose category</option>
                          <?php foreach ($all_category as $row_category) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row_category["category_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row_category["category_name"]; ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select>

                        <label for="item_name"><b>Item Name</b>
                          <font color="red">
                            <p style="font-size: 8px;"><b>
                                <?php echo form_error('item_name'); ?></b></p>
                          </font>
                        </label>
                        <input onfocus="var temp_value=this.value; this.value=''; this.value=temp_value" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('item_name'); ?>" class="form-control" id="edit_item_name" name="item_name">






                        <label for="price"><b>Price</b>
                          <font color="red">
                            <p style="font-size: 8px;"><b>
                                <?php echo form_error('price'); ?></b></p>
                          </font>
                        </label>
                        <input onfocus="var temp_value=this.value; this.value=''; this.value=temp_value" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('price'); ?>" id="edit_price" class="form-control" name="price" required autofocus="">


                        <label for="status">Status</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="edit_status" name="status">
                          <option value="1">Registered</option>
                          <option value="2">Alloted</option>
                          <option value="3">Maintenance</option>
                          <option value="4">Retired</option>
                        </select>

                        <label for="type">Type</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="edit_type_id" name="type_id">
                          <option value="1" disabled selected>Choose Type</option>
                          <?php foreach ($all_type as $row_type) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row_type["type_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row_type["type_name"]; ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select>

                        <!-- <label for="user_id">Select User</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="edit_user_id" name="user_id">
                          <option value="1" disabled selected>Choose user</option>
                          <//?php foreach ($all_user as $row_user) { ?>
                            <option value="<//?php echo $row_user["user_id"]; ?>"><//?php echo $row_user["u_name"]; ?></option>
                          <//?php } ?>
                        </select>  -->

                        <!-- <label for="user">Select User</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="edit_user_id" name="user_id">
                          <//?php foreach ($all_user as $row_user) { ?>
                            <//?php if ($row_user["user_id"] == $selected_user_id) { ?>
                              <option value="<//?php echo $row_user["user_id"]; ?>" selected><//?php echo $row_user["u_name"]; ?></option>
                            <//?php } else { ?>
                              <option value="<//?php echo $row_user["user_id"]; ?>"><//?php echo $row_user["u_name"]; ?></option>
                            <//?php } ?>
                          <//?php } ?>
                        </select> -->

                        <!-- <label for="comment"><b>Remarks</b>
                          <font color="red">
                            <p style="font-size: 8px;"><b>
                                <//?php echo form_error('comment'); ?></b></p>
                          </font>
                        </label>
                        <input onfocus="var temp_value=this.value; this.value=''; this.value=temp_value" type="text" value="<//?php echo set_value('comment'); ?>" class="form-control" id="edit_remarks" name="comment">
 -->


                        <br>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <label for="purchase_date"><b>Purchase Date</b></label>

                          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="edit_purchase_date" disabled name="purchase_date" value="" required autofocus>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <label for="maintenance_due_date"><b>Maintenance Due Date</b></label>

                          <input type="date" class="form-control" data-mask name="maintenance_due_date" id="edit_maintenance_due_date" value="" required autofocus>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['user_id']); ?>" id="edit_by_user" class="form-control" name="by_user" required>
                      <input type="hidden" value="1" class="form-control" name="type" required>
                      <input type="hidden" value="0" class="form-control" name="requisition_slip_id" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-footer" style="background-color: #ECF0F5;">
                      <button type="submit" id="editsubmitbtn" style="width: 20%;float: left;" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                      <a href="<?php echo base_url() . "Add_Item/show_item" ?>">
                        <button type="button" style="width: 20%;float: left;margin-left: 5%;" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
edit modal end
```

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.open-update-modal-btn').click(function() {
        var rowData = $(this).data('item');

        console.log("______");
        console.log(rowData);
        console.log(rowData.item_id);
        //console.log(rowData.type_id);
        console.log(rowData.user_id);

        // Populate your modal or form fields with the retrieved data
        $('#item_id').val(rowData.item_id);
        $('#edit_brand_id').val(rowData.brand_id);
        $('#edit_category_id').val(rowData.category_id);
        $('#edit_item_name').val(rowData.item_name);
        $('#edit_price').val(rowData.price);
        $('#edit_status').val(rowData.status);
        $('#edit_type_id').val(rowData.type_id);
        $('#edit_purchase_date').val(rowData.purchase_date);
        $('#edit_remarks').val(rowData.remarks);
        $('#edit_maintenance_due_date').val(rowData.maintenance_due_date);
        $('#edit_by_user').val(rowData.by_user);
        // Populate other fields in your modal or form as needed
      });


      $('#editsubmitbtn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

        // Get form data
        var formData = $('#editForm').serialize();

        console.log(formData);
        // Send AJAX request
        $.ajax({
          url: '<?php echo base_url("Add_Item/update_item_id"); ?>',
          type: 'POST',
          data: formData,
          success: function(response) {
            if (response) {
              alert('Data updated successfully: ' + response);
              console.log('Data updated successfully:', response);
              $('#editNewItemModal').modal('hide');
              // Optionally, close the modal or perform any other actions
            } else {
              alert('Error: ' + response);
            }
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log(error); // Log the error to the console for debugging
          }
        }); // <-- Here's the missing closing bracket
      });
    });
  </script>
show_item.php
this is my ajax request.
```

this is my controller Add_Item.php

```
 function update_item_id()

    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
       // var_dump($id);
        $data = array(
            
            'brand_id'=>$this->input->post('brand_id'),
            'category_id'=>$this->input->post('category_id'),
            'item_name' => $this->input->post('item_name'),
            'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
            'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
            'type_id' => $this->input->post('type_id'),
            'purchase_date'=>$this->input->post('purchase_date'),
            'maintenance_due_date' => $this->input->post('maintenance_due_date'),
            'by_user' => $this->input->post('by_user'),
        );
       // var_dump($id, $data); // Debugging

        $result=$this->Itnhs->update_item_id($id, $data);
       
        // var_dump(  $this->Itnhs->update_item_id($id, $data));
       // $updatedData = $this->Itnhs->show_item_id($id);
       // var_dump($data);
      if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        // Fetch the updated data (if needed)
        //$updatedData = $this->Itnhs->show_item_id($id);
       //var_dump($result);
        // Return a JSON response with success status, message, and updated data
        if ($result) {
            // Data updated successfully
            echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Item edited Successfully'));
        } else {
            // Failed to update data
            echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Failed to edit item.'));
        }
   
        
    
        // Send JSON response
       // $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($response));
    
   //     redirect("Add_Item/show_item");
    }
}
```

Comment: why iam not getting any help regarding this?

Comment: can you format this a bit better and provide a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example